# KMeans clustering multidimensional features

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, k-means, word2vec

Is it possible to train a Kmeans ML model using a multidimensional feature matrix?

I'm using sklearn and KmeansClass for clustering, Word2Vec for extracting the bag of words, and TreeTagger for the text pre-processing

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

lemmatized_words = [["be", "information", "contract", "residential"], ["can", "send", "package", "recovery"]

w2v_model = Word2Vec.load(wiki_path_model)

bag_of_words = [w2v_model.wv(phrase) for phrase in lemmatized_words]

#
#
# bag_of_words = [array([[-0.08796783,  0.08373307,  0.04610106, ...,  0.41964772,
#        -0.1733183 ,  0.09438939],
#       [ 0.11526374,  0.09092105, -0.2086806 , ...,  0.5205145 ,
#        -0.11455593, -0.05190944],
#       [-0.05140354,  0.09938619,  0.07485678, ...,  0.73840886,
#        -0.17298238,  0.09994634],
#       ...,
#       [-0.01144416, -0.17129216, -0.04012141, ...,  0.05281362,
#        -0.23109615,  0.02297313],
#       [-0.08355679,  0.24799444,  0.04348441, ...,  0.27940673,
#        -0.14400786, -0.09187686],
#       [ 0.11022831,  0.11035886,  0.19900796, ...,  0.12891224,
#        -0.09379898,  0.10538024]],dtype=float32)
#       array([[ 1.73330009e-01,  1.26429915e-01, -3.47578406e-01, ...,
#         8.09064806e-02, -3.02738965e-01, -1.61911864e-02],
#       [ 2.47227158e-02, -6.48087710e-02, -1.97364464e-01, ...,
#         1.35158226e-01,  1.72204189e-02, -1.14456110e-01],
#       [ 8.07424933e-02,  2.69261692e-02, -4.22120057e-02, ...,
#         1.01349883e-01, -1.94084793e-01, -2.64464412e-04],
#       ...,
#       [ 1.36009008e-01,  1.50609210e-01, -2.59797573e-01, ...,
#         1.84113771e-01, -6.85161874e-02, -1.04138054e-01],
#       [ 4.83367145e-02,  1.17820159e-01, -2.43335906e-02, ...,
#         1.33836940e-01, -1.55749675e-02, -1.18981823e-01],
#       [-6.68482706e-02,  4.57039356e-01, -2.20365867e-01, ...,
#         2.95841128e-01, -1.55933857e-01,  7.39804050e-03]], dtype=float32)
#       ]
#
#

model = KMeans(algorithm='auto0', max_iter=300, n_clusters=2)

model.fit(bag_of_words)
```

I expect that the Kmeans is trained, so I can store the model and use for predictions, but I receive this error message:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Why (and what is) `self.X_train`?

Comment: Sorry, It's a mistake in order to simplify the code

Comment: But what is `X_train`? Doesn't appear before in your code

Comment: `X_train` is `bag_of_words`, the Kmeans cluster is embedded in a specific class where contains `X_train`. Instead of showing class = KmeansClass(X_train) and call `class.train(), I wrote model.fit(X_train), I'm going to correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in `w2v_model.wv(phrase)`. Word2vec model, as it name implies, can be applied on the word level. To obtain phrase embeddings, you need to average (or aggregate in some other way) embeddings of all individial words in this phrase.

So you need to replace

```
bag_of_words = [w2v_model.wv(phrase) for phrase in lemmatized_words]
```

with

```
import numpy as np
bag_of_words = [np.mean([w2v_model.wv(word) for word in phrase], axis=0) for phrase in lemmatized_words]
```

For me, the following code snipped worked OK. It uses `KeyedVectors` instead of deprecated `Word2Vec`, but all the rest is the same.

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
lemmatized_words = [["be", "information", "contract", "residential"], ["can", "send", "package", "recovery"]]
w2v_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(wiki_path_model, binary=True)  
bag_of_words = np.array([np.mean([w2v_model[word] for word in phrase if word in w2v_model], axis=0) for phrase in lemmatized_words])
print(bag_of_words.shape) # it should give (2, 300) for a 300-dimensional w2v
model = KMeans( max_iter=300, n_clusters=2)
model.fit(bag_of_words)
```

Of course, averaging (or other aggregation) discards some information about words, and this information might be meaningful for clustering. But without aggregation, you cannot get comparable phrase embeddings, because different phrases may have different lengths.

If your clustering of average embeddings fails, I would recommend to look for pretrained sentence embeddings (e.g. Google's Universal Sentence Encoder, or maybe embeddings from BERT).

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the answer. If I try to apply word2vec on every word in the phrase, in order to obtain multidimensional feature for a single row, I receive the same error. The problem is not on the w2v_model.wv(phrase), but is on KMeans. Is it possible to apply KMeans on a matrix with multidimensional features for each row?

Comment: What exacty do you mean by "multidimensional feature"? My suggestion is to use an average vector of all words as a sentence embedding. It is a 1D vector. E.g. if your model has 300-dimensional embeddings, then each sentence will be represented as a list of 300 numbers.

Comment: Instead of [[1.12, 2.03, 3.2], [1.78, 2.3, 0.2]] (in this case, 1x2 matrix), I have [[[1.12, 2.03, 3.2], [1.78, 2.3, 0.2]], [[1.12, 2.03, 3.2], [1.78, 2.3, 0.2]] (so a 1x2 matrix, but beach column is an array instead of a float).

Comment: In this case, you should call `np.concat()` on your list of matrices, before feeding it into k-means. Or use my version of the code (I updated the answer); it gives correct vectors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer David. I've already implemented your solution using the average. My idea was to try a KMeans and add zeros vectors in order to obtain the same length for each starting phrase. The other option is using BERT, but first I'll try with this one. Thanks again for the answer